# How to use our naming convention in Azure Blueprints?

Tags: azure, deployment

How can we apply our own naming conventions when deploying infrastructure with Azure Blueprints?

Answer (score 0):

It looks similar to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2be1d7b-78af-4662-9104-71badfaafefc/how-can-we-apply-our-own-naming-conventions-when-deploying-infrastructure-with-azure-blueprints?forum=azureautomation) MSDN thread which has below answer for it. Hope it helps!

*BluePrints is made of RBAC, Policy and ARM.   So you can use a policy for naming conventions.  An example of this is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/allow-multiple-name-patterns) and is especially useful for differentiating subscriptions in the same tenant.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend managing blueprints-as-code for establishing naming conventions. You can use the concat function in combination with input parameters to set a naming convention just like you can do in ARM templates.

https://github.com/azure/azure-blueprints